# How to set AlaramManager to create reminder application?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, reminders

I create a reminder application. I used AlarmManager to set alarm for user. but sometimes it works with delay (near 5 minutes).
This is my alarm receiver that I set alarm for user with this class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int mReceivedID = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID));

        // Get notification title from Reminder Database
        ReminderDatabase rb = new ReminderDatabase(context);
        Reminder reminder = rb.getReminder(mReceivedID);
        String mTitle = reminder.getTitle();

        // Create intent to open ReminderEditActivity on notification click
        Intent editIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderEditActivity.class);
        editIntent.putExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(mReceivedID));
        PendingIntent mClick = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mReceivedID, editIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Create Notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
          .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_on_white_24dp)
          .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
          .setTicker(mTitle)
          .setContentText(mTitle)
          .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
          .setContentIntent(mClick)
          .setAutoCancel(true)
          .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nManager.notify(mReceivedID, mBuilder.build());
    }
    public void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int ID) {

        // Put Reminder ID in Intent  Extra
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(ID));

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }

        // Restart alarm if device is rebooted
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
          PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
          PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }


    public void setRepeatAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int ID, long RepeatTime) {

        // Put Reminder ID in Intent Extra
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(ID));
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), RepeatTime, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm set for " + calendar.getTime().toLocaleString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("lllooo", "alarm set for " + calendar.getTime().toLocaleString());


        // Restart alarm if device is rebooted
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
          PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
          PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }

    public void cancelAlarm(Context context, int ID) {
        mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Cancel Alarm using Reminder ID
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
        mAlarmManager.cancel(mPendingIntent);

        // Disable alarm
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
          PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
          PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
}
```

For example when I set an alarm for 10:00 Am it will run at 10:05 Am!
I searched a lot but nothing worked for me!

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676553/android-alarm-manager-working-but-delayed

Comment: I saw this post before but in my code i used setExact method! but it doesn't work correctly.